# iOS 8 - Adding user input before CoreData updates object and tableView

Tags: core-data, swift, ios8

I'm barely new to iOS (Swift or otherwise) programming.

I've started coding an App using Master-Detail Application (with `CoreData`) template.

The problem I have is I cannot find the way to make the user input data ***and then*** take these values into the `newManagedObject`.

No matter how I do it (i.e., alerts or even another view) `CoreData` creates the object first (giving an error cause variable value is empty) and then presents the user with the option to input data (although whatever method I user to present data is always before the **`newManagedObject.setvalue`** execution line.

Thanks!

Comment: How/where are you telling CoreData to create a new object?  How/where are you getting input?  (It's quite possible to create a new object, then update its properties, then save it.)

Comment: Table view controller that's the root segue. Has a "+" navigator button with an action (just as it is created by apple from the Master-Detail App template).

Comment: In the action, entity and context are fetched and then the object gets created. I found a way around it by using alerts to get user data, and had to move the object creation along with entity and context fetching to the okButton action within the alert. It's the only way, so far, that I managed to get the result I expected, but I guess there has to be another way so I don't **have** to use alerts

Comment: It would help if you would edit your question to show the code you're using that's failing.

Comment: Hi Tom, I completely forgot to close this thread. It's been resolved a long time ago.

Comment: I'll try to search for the code and show the solution or workaround I used.